# WebViewClient shows white screen

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm new to Android app development.
I'm managing to show a WebView and load a given URL. When I click on a link in the WebView, I get a blank white screen.

When I use the Chrome browser on the device (Galaxy TAB), it's working. Actually i'm trying to imitate Chrome in my WebView.

Does anyone know what's the problem?

This is the WebViewClient I use in my WebView:

```
siteView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString) {

                    siteView.loadUrl(urlNewString);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

                    if (dialog == null || !dialog.isShowing()) {

                        if(isFirstTime) {

                            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, "", getString(R.string.loadingMessage), true, false);
                            MyActivity.isFirstTime = false;
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                        String description, String failingUrl) {

                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem may lie in your shouldOverrideUrlLoading function. Your are receiving "view" as a parameter and you using "siteView" to load url. Your function should look like:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString) {

        view.loadUrl(urlNewString); // you are using siteView here instead of view
        return true;
    }
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: the docs for `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` clearly state that you should return false to let the web view load the URL normally. what you have above is equivalent to simply returning false.

Answer (score 4):

try `siteView.invalidate()`
before loading anything to webview

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the url starts with **http://**. Without http it will just show white screen. Because mostly you will copy url and it will start with `www.something.com/asdf`. That will not work. change it to `http://www.something.com/asdf`.